# Weak* sequential density vs weak* density

Tags: banach-spaces, weak-topology, dense-subspaces

Let $X$ be a separable Banach space. Is it true that a weak* dense subspace of $X^{\ast}$ is also weak* sequentially dense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe this to be true in general.
However, for a subspace with the property that its weak-$\ast$-ly sequential "closure" is convex and weak-$\ast$-ly sequentially closed this is indeed true and follows from the Krein-Smulian theorem:

Let $\mathrm{cl}^*$ denote the closure operator in the weak-$\ast$ topology and define the weak-$\ast$-ly sequential "closure" operator
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{scl}^* A = \left\{ \phi \in X^* \mid \exists\, \text{sequence } (\phi_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \text{ in } A: \phi_n \xrightarrow{\text{weak-$\ast$}} \phi \; (n \to \infty) \right\} \, .
\end{equation}
**Note that $\mathrm{scl}^*$ is [not idempotent in general](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373491/is-w-sequential-closure-idempotent).**
Furthermore, let $B_r(0)$ denote the open ball of radius $r > 0$ in $X^*$.

**Lemma:**
Let $A \subseteq X^*$ be convex and weak-$\ast$-ly sequentially closed.
Then $A$ is weak-$\ast$-ly closed.

*proof:*
Suppose that there is some $r > 0$ such that $A \cap \overline{B_r(0)}$ is not weak-$\ast$-ly sequentially closed.
Then there is a sequence $(\phi_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $A \cap \overline{B_r(0)}$ converging weak-$\ast$-ly to some $\phi \in X^* \setminus [A \cap \overline{B_r(0)}]$.
Since $A$ is sequentially closed, $\phi \in A$ and thus $\Vert \phi \Vert > r$.
However, the norm in $X^*$ is [weak-$\ast$-ly lower semicontinuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3325756/is-operatory-norm-weak-lower-semicontinuous), providing a contradiction.
Consequently, $A \cap \overline{B_r(0)}$  is weak-$\ast$-ly sequentially closed and thus weak-$\ast$-ly closed since bounded sets in the weak-$\ast$ topology are metrisable since $X$ is separable by the [sequential Banach-Alaoglu theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem#Sequential_Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem).
Hence [Krein-Smulian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krein%E2%80%93Smulian_theorem) applies.

**Corollary:**
Let $A \subseteq X^*$ be weak-$\ast$-ly dense and

- $\mathrm{scl}^* A$ is convex (e.g. $A$ is itself convex)
- $\mathrm{scl}^* A$ is sequentially closed (this might be difficult in practice).

Then $A$ is weak-$\ast$-ly sequentially dense.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=c_0$, and $W\subseteq c_0^*=\ell^1$ be defined by $$W=\{(c_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \in\ell^1: c_0 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_k\} $$

For $a=(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \in c_0$, if $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} c_na_n=0 \hspace{8mm}\forall c= (c_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \in W$$ then $a=0$. Thus, $W$ is a separating subspace, so weak$^*$ dense in $\ell^1$.

Please see [Theorem 1](https://books.google.ca/books?id=jN6tnsBU_IMC&pg=PA127) in the Appendix of the book *"Theory of Linear Operations"* by Banach, which proves that $W$ is not weak$^*$ sequentially dense (and more).

Comment: It's hard to read Banach's own text. The language seems outdated to me. But I believe I have a proof that $W$ is weak* sequentially dense: if $(c_k) \in \ell^1$, consider for all $n \geq 1$ the sequence $(c^{(n)}_k)_k \in W$ defined by $c_k^{(n)} = c_k$ for all $k \neq n$ and $c_n^{(n)} = c_0 + c_n - \sum_{k = 1}^\infty c_k$. Then for all $(a_k) \in c_0$, one has $\langle (a_k), (c_k^{(n)}) \rangle = \langle (a_k), (c_k) \rangle + (c_0 - \sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k) a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ since $a_n \to 0$, meaning that $c^{(n)} \to c$ (weak* convergence). What is wrong here?

Comment: @vizietto your argument is correct. Instead of $W$ above, please consider the space defined in eq. (5) in the proof of Theorem 1 in Banach's book. In the proof, "weakly closed" means weak-star sequentially closed, "weak closure" means weak-star sequential closure, "weakly dense" means weak-star sequentially dense, etc.. which is the only 1930s-2020s translator we need.

Comment: I cannot see why the space defined in eq (5) is weak* dense in $\ell^1$.